# Access angular js controller variables from native javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this is dirty but I need to access and edit a variable in an angular js controller from an outside function that is not angular js. How can I do it?

```
module.controller('table', function($rootScope, $scope, $modal, $q, $compile, $timeout,fields, querySrv, dashboard, filterSrv) {
  var _d = {
    size    : 100
  }
}
```

Function:

```
get_var = function(){
    console.log("get_var");
    console.log(document.???);
}
```

Comment: Why have you to do this trick ? Can you try to be more precise ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, you need to get the `scope` object of the controller. I would go with a way which i know:

To get scope of the controller, You must get the reference of the DOM element and call `scope()`

If for example, particular Dom element is having the `mg-controller` set then

```
var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector(".selectorHere")).scope();
```

Now you can access any **scope** properties here.

```
scope.myVariable = "set some value";
```

But since you're working out of angular scope, you must trigger the digest cycle manually using the $apply().

```
scope.$apply();
```